# Cakephp - not loading css and js

Tags: cakephp, assets

I'm a rails developer doing some patchwork on a cakephp project.

I pulled from a repository and am trying to get a local version of the project up and running.

Right now, the application is trying to load assets from 'localhost/static/css'

The css is actually located in localhost/app-name/app/webroot/static/css.

I've renamed all the htaccess files (app-name/.htaccess, app/.htaccess, app/webroot/.htaccess) and commented them out, but the app is still looking for my assets at 'localhost/static/'.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `.htaccess` files!

Do you have mod_rewrite installed and enabled?

Do you have allow_override All set for your application `webroot` in you `apache config?` (So apache will read the CakePHP `.htaccess` files)

Did you clear the cache? (Remove all the files, but leave the directories in place in `app/tmp` - and make sure `app/tmp` is `readable/writable` by the webserver

Are you missing a symbolic link? I store my assets outside of `webroot` and symbolically link the directories (css, js, img, etc.) to `/app/webroot`

Answer (score 2):

Don't remove **.htaccess** files. As in mine case I was facing same problem and now it's working fine. 
Trick is simple, just ho to **Apache directory**, and open httpd.conf and search for rewrite_module and remove comment(#) from that line i.e. 
 
**#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so** will be 
**LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so**

Answer (score 1):

First you don't have to delete .htaccess and be sure that mod_rewrite is enabled into your localhost.
Second In cakephp there is a great helper called `Html`
If you want to load a js try this into your view:

```
echo $this->Html->script('your_js.js');
```

this js have to be into your app/webroot/js

Instead for css try to use:

```
echo $this->Html->css('your_css.css');
```

Css have to be in this folder: app/webroot/css

cakephp have already its path but you have to respect convention

Comment: I enabled mod_rewrite but the app is still looking for assets in "localhost/static/". Any other ideas?

Comment: please add to your question the file routes in config and an example of your incorrect path @Squadrons